# multiple scenario text matching to a table via TSQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am looking to see if there is a better way to write the stored procedure in this following scenario:

**Scenario**

I have a piece of text which needs to be matched against the full name of a person in a person table to get his unique id

**Challenge**

In attempting to match various patterns, the function that I have written has become the costliest query in the batch (per execution plan). As I run this several times against half a million records of a table containing the text, alongside the persons table containing 100,000+ persons.

**Person Table (relevant columns) sample**

```
uniquepersonid  FullName
------------------------------
12345           John Doe
23456           Jane Doe
```

Text could be in any of the following formats (or more):

1. John Doe
2. John Doe.
3. John Doe,
4. John Doe (member)
5. Jane Doe/
6. John Doe et al.

**Function**

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_Extract_Person] 
       (@text as nvarchar(1000))
    RETURNS int
    AS
    BEGIN
         declare @result int

         --direct comparison         
         select @result = uniquepersonid 
         from persons 
         where fullname = ltrim(rtrim(@text))

         if (@result > 0)
             return @result
    end
    --eliminate / and .
    set @text = replace(@text,'/','')
    set @text = replace(@text,'.','')

    select @result = uniquepersonid 
    from persons 
    where fullname = ltrim(rtrim(@text))

    if (@result > 0)
         return @result
    end

    --eliminate comma
    set @text = replace(@text,',','')

    select @result = uniquepersonid 
    from persons 
    where fullname = ltrim(rtrim(@text))

    -- and so on for other patterns  
    return @result
END
```

Comment: How do you determine when/where the full name ends? What about people with 2 last names that are not hyphenated (e.g. "Paul van Dyk" or "Reginald Von Hoobie-Doobie")? What about duplicate names (e.g. "John Smith")? Something seems a little off here. Regardless, your function would be much faster if you didn't do 3 SELECTs against `person`. Just do the 3 REPLACEs and then a single SELECT. That's at  least a start prior to getting something more ideal in place.

Comment: Fortunately, it is a pattern followed in the text where the name is always succeeded by a set of patterns (already identified during our analysis). As long as the name matches the person table (be it one or two last names), it should still work out for us. Some patterns are also complex where the text does not start with a person name all the time.

Answer (score 1):

To have a better performance I would suggest you to add a `computed column` to your table then set your function as formula, so far for each record the pure name will be calculated, but this won't make a significant improvement on your query. To solve that set `IsPersisted` property on the computed column to true, then go and make your query again, you will be surprised.

Comment: Computed Column is a brilliant idea. However in my case the text is being parsed and one of the steps is to extract the unique id. 
Example: "John Doe, of the community college of xyz" is one of the patterns which when split, will get me John Doe, as the text to extract the uniquepersonid. The text may or may not contain a person.

Answer (score 1):

You have indexed Fullname, haven't you? Assuming you have, maybe this approach helps

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_Extract_Person] 
       (@text as nvarchar(1000))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    declare @result INT

    WITH options AS(
        SELECT * FROM (VALUES
              (1, ltrim(rtrim(@text)))
            , (2, ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(@text,'/',''),'.',''))))
            , (3, ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(@text,'/',''),'.',''),',',''))))
            , (4, ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING(@text,1,PATINDEX('%[(.{]%', @text)))))
        ) AS T(Prio, Name)
    )
    SELECT TOP 1 @result = uniquepersonid, Prio FROM dbo.persons AS P
        INNER JOIN options AS O
            ON P.name = O.name
    ORDER BY Prio;

    if (@result > 0)
        return @result
END
```

**EDIT:** Using a scalar function might be even more of problem that the contents of it depending on how you're using the function. Using this function query for instance is a bad idea. In that case you probably need to go for an inline function, like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IF_Extract_Person] 
       (@text as nvarchar(1000))
RETURNS TABLE RETURN
    WITH options AS(
        SELECT * FROM (VALUES
              (1, ltrim(rtrim(@text)))
            , (2, ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(@text,'/',''),'.',''))))
            , (3, ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(@text,'/',''),'.',''),',',''))))
            , (4, ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING(@text,1,PATINDEX('%[(.{]%', @text)))))
        ) AS T(Prio, Name)
    )
    SELECT TOP 1 uniquepersonid FROM dbo.persons AS P
        INNER JOIN options AS O
            ON P.name = O.name
    ORDER BY O.Prio
GO
```

**EDIT2:** Made a few optimizations, maybe that helps. You might want to give a bit more context and tell us how the function is being used.

Comment: Interesting approach. Not sure, but this function took more time when combined with my other function. I added about 6 criteria to begin with. thoughts?